# Is there a specific noun for graphs with exactly connectivity $k$?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, graph-connectivity

The (vertex-)connectivity $\kappa(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the minimum number of
vertices whose removal from $G$ leaves a disconnected or a trivial graph. A graph $G$ with connectivity $\kappa ≥ k ≥ 1$ is called $k$-connected.

If the connectivity of a graph is exactly $k$, is there a noun that defines such a graph?
I vaguely remember seeing it somewhere, but I can't seem to find it at the moment. Since I will frequently describe such graphs, I thought having a specific noun for them would make the descriptions more convenient.